Automate Mouse Clicks on Mac
For years I have used the following code on a Mac to automate mouse clicks in my bash scripts.  Recently (sometime since I upgraded to Sonoma?) it stopped working.
Here is the code:
// Compile instructions:
//
// gcc -o click click.c -Wall -framework ApplicationServices

#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int x = 0, y = 0, n = 1;
  float duration = 0.1;

  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("USAGE: click X Y [N] [DURATION]\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  x = atoi(argv[1]);
  y = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (argc >= 4) {
    n = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  if (argc >= 5) {
    duration = atof(argv[4]);
  }

  CGEventRef click_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
    NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
    CGPointMake(x, y),
    kCGMouseButtonLeft
  );

  CGEventRef click_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
    NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
    CGPointMake(x, y),
    kCGMouseButtonLeft
  );

  // Now, execute these events with an interval to make them noticeable
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_down);
    sleep(duration);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_up);
    sleep(duration);
  }

  // Release the events
  CFRelease(click_down);
  CFRelease(click_up);

  return 0;
}

I usually call it like this: ~/bin/click 0 24 10
I get the following logs when I run the code:
default 10:36:08.110246-0700    kernel  map_with_linking_np: [3698(click)]: region 0, not code signed
default 10:36:08.115969-0700    click   server port 0x00001303, session port 0x00001303
default 10:36:08.116278-0700    click   [0x600003da8000] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.tccd.system
default 10:36:08.117151-0700    tccd    AUTHREQ_ATTRIBUTION: msgID=3698.1, attribution={responsible={TCCDProcess: identifier=com.googlecode.iterm2, pid=91606, auid=501, euid=501, responsible_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2, binary_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2}, requesting={TCCDProcess: identifier=<ID of InvalidCode>, pid=3698, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Users/thewellington/bin/click}, },
default 10:36:08.120637-0700    click   [0x600003da8000] invalidated after the last release of the connection object
default 10:36:08.123408-0700    tccd    AUTHREQ_ATTRIBUTION: msgID=169.2640, attribution={responsible={TCCDProcess: identifier=com.googlecode.iterm2, pid=91606, auid=501, euid=501, responsible_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2, binary_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2}, accessing={TCCDProcess: identifier=<ID of InvalidCode>, pid=3698, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Users/thewellington/bin/click}, requesting={TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.WindowServer, pid=169, auid=88, euid=88, binary_path=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer}, },
default 10:36:08.123466-0700    tccd    requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.WindowServer, pid=169, auid=88, euid=88, binary_path=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer is checking access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=<ID of InvalidCode>, pid=3698, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Users/thewellington/bin/click
default 10:36:08.129318-0700    click   [0x600003da0000] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.cfprefsd.daemon
default 10:36:08.129492-0700    click   [0x600003db4000] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.cfprefsd.agent
default 10:36:08.133421-0700    click   [0x600003db40f0] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.tccd.system
default 10:36:08.134222-0700    tccd    AUTHREQ_ATTRIBUTION: msgID=3698.2, attribution={responsible={TCCDProcess: identifier=com.googlecode.iterm2, pid=91606, auid=501, euid=501, responsible_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2, binary_path=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2}, requesting={TCCDProcess: identifier=<ID of InvalidCode>, pid=3698, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Users/thewellington/bin/click}, },
default 10:36:08.136957-0700    click   [0x600003db40f0] invalidated after the last release of the connection object
default 10:36:08.137146-0700    click   server port 0x00001603, session port 0x00001303
default 10:36:08.137927-0700    tccd    SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: click[3698]/0#-1 LF=3

I have recompiled the code, and I have tried to reach out to who I believe was the original developer - but I can't find current contact info for them.
I believe, from the logs that I might be running into some privacy setting with MacOS and it gets tighter and tighter.  I have added ~/usr/bin/click to Privacy & Security > Accessibility but it no longer simulates mouse clicks anymore.
It would be great to know what permissions I would need to grant this code, or what changes need to be made so that I can resume automating mouse clicks.
Thank you in advance for any help you may provide in pointing me in the right direction.
Bill
